# activate and use pound proxy for domain names on dd/wrt v24 sp2

Tags: dd-wrt, pound

I would like to activate and use pound on DD-WRT v24-sp2 (07/24/13) mega but I didn't find any option in router administration. Please how can I activate and use it?

Answer (score 0):

Pound doesn't actually come on standard builds of DD-WRT, it may have been a custom build that was referred to.
You will need to get it via Optware, so that needs to be set up, but once it is the configuration appears simple enough (you will need to edit it by hand since there is no GUI for it).